# re-ordering factors according to a value using fct_reorder in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

My data:

```
structure(list(LoB = c("C", "C", "C", "A", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B"), word = c("speed", 
"connection", "call", "bt", "reliable", "reliable", "reliable", 
"expensive", "cheaper", "uk", "customer", "customer", "customer", 
"network", "broadband", "broadband", "signal", "price", "price", 
"price", "poor", "poor", "ee", "service", "service", "service", 
"excellent", "excellent", "excellent", "coverage"), word_total = c(68L, 
46L, 44L, 3138L, 3479L, 906L, 71L, 6096L, 2967L, 39L, 10405L, 
1429L, 113L, 676L, 5193L, 73L, 868L, 8763L, 814L, 139L, 4708L, 
659L, 530L, 19185L, 2253L, 136L, 7180L, 1227L, 69L, 1453L), word_prop_by_total_feedbacks = c(0.0656370656370656, 
0.0444015444015444, 0.0424710424710425, 0.0343378635677237, 0.0380692885124636, 
0.101603678367164, 0.0685328185328185, 0.0667060600091918, 0.0324666797977808, 
0.0376447876447876, 0.113857702492723, 0.160255691376023, 0.109073359073359, 
0.075810250084109, 0.0568248965924759, 0.0704633204633205, 0.0973421554334417, 
0.0958899612632132, 0.0912863070539419, 0.134169884169884, 0.0515177379467314, 
0.0739037792979702, 0.0594370303913872, 0.209933687873416, 0.252663451833576, 
0.131274131274131, 0.0785678331473092, 0.137602332623079, 0.0666023166023166, 
0.16294717954469)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), vars = "LoB", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    c(3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 26L), c(5L, 11L, 
    13L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 27L, 29L), c(0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
    9L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 25L, 28L)), group_sizes = c(10L, 10L, 
10L), biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(LoB = c("A", 
"B", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
), vars = "LoB", drop = TRUE, .Names = "LoB"), .Names = c("LoB", 
"word", "word_total", "word_prop_by_total_feedbacks"))
```

I am trying to plot using `ggplot2` but `fct_reorder` and `drlib::reorder_within(word, word_total, LoB)` not working and giving me a warning message: `Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector`

Here is the code:

```
   mutate(word = drlib::reorder_within(word, word_total, LoB)) %>%
```

**OR**

```
  mutate(word = forcats::fct_reorder(word, word_total)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, word_prop_by_total_feedbacks, fill = LoB)) +
  geom_col() +
#  drlib::scale_x_reordered()+
  facet_wrap(~ LoB, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

it is not plotting in descending order. what am I missing?

**Update:** Was missing `ungroup()` before `mutate()`. thanks all

Comment: It's not plotting in descending order of what? `word`? With me it is and I did not run `mutate`, just your data as posted. And you are missing the name of the data frame both in the question and in the `ggplot(df, aes(...))`.

Comment: You may have been missing an `ungroup` at some earlier step.  I've made this mistake before.

Comment: this was exactly what I was missing...all sorted...thanks @aosmith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @austensen, but using a different method for the `factor` averse.

You can just `group_by` and `arrange` accordingly, then `ungroup` and create and index.  This way you don't have to worry about using `factor`, but you do have to create `breaks` and `labels` in `scale_x_continuous`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

plot_data <- df %>% 
  group_by(LoB) %>% 
  arrange(word_total) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number())

ggplot(plot_data, aes(order, word_prop_by_total_feedbacks, fill = LoB)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ LoB, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = plot_data$order, labels = plot_data$word) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an awkward work-around because you can have the same word appear in different order based on the value of `LoB`. There is a good example of this from the book [Tidy Text Mining](http://tidytextmining.com/nasa.html) (see section `8.4.3` of this chapter). I followed that to create what's below.

Essentially you have to order `word` as the concatenation of `word` and `LoB` then strip the `LoB` part out when displaying the word labels on the graph.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  group_by(LoB) %>% 
  arrange(desc(word_total)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(word = factor(paste(word, LoB, sep = "__"), 
                       levels = rev(paste(word, LoB, sep = "__")))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, word_prop_by_total_feedbacks, fill = LoB)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub("__.+$", "", x)) +
  facet_wrap(~ LoB, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider `tidytext::reorder_within`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(LoB) %>% 
  arrange(desc(word_total)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(word_prop_by_total_feedbacks, tidytext::reorder_within(word, word_prop_by_total_feedbacks, LoB), fill = LoB)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ LoB, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_reordered()
```