# Reordering within groups not working on ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have followed this example:
[re-ordering factors according to a value using fct_reorder in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977508/re-ordering-factors-according-to-a-value-using-fct-reorder-in-r)

Here is a dput of my top5_producers variable

```
structure(list(iso3_code = c("BGD", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "DEU", 
"EGY", "IDN", "IDN", "IND", "IND", "JPN", "KOR", "MEX", "MEX", 
"MMR", "NLD", "NLD", "PAK", "VNM", "VNM"), country = c("Bangladesh", 
"China", "China", "China", "Germany", "Egypt", "Indonesia", "Indonesia", 
"India", "India", "Japan", "South korea", "Mexico", "Mexico", 
"Myanmar", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Pakistan", "Viet Nam", 
"Viet Nam"), source_crop = c("Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", 
"Soybeans", "Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", "Maize", "Soybeans", 
"Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", "Sugar cane", "Maize", "Maize", 
"Maize", "Soybeans", "Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", "Soybeans", 
"Oil palm fruit", "Maize", "Soybeans"), FC_imports = c(1949020L, 
5457164L, 84505368L, 3062047L, 2201599L, 8652235L, 6311197L, 
4761885L, 8335597L, 2119435L, 15342352L, 9804926L, 14217581L, 
6540675L, 2205780L, 3867813L, 7534711L, 2817298L, 8228098L, 6273590L
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f953580b2e0>, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my code

```
plot_data = top5_producers %>% 
  group_by(source_crop) %>% 
  arrange(source_crop, FC_imports) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number())

plot_data %>%  
  ggplot(aes(y = FC_imports, x = country, fill = source_crop)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~source_crop, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = plot_data$order, labels = plot_data$country) +
  coord_flip()
```

This is my output

[image: bar plot with facets]

I want bars to be sorted from within each group, but I can't get the code to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your variables:

```
plot_data %>%  
  ggplot(aes(reorder(y = FC_imports, x = country, fill = source_crop), FC_imports)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~source_crop, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = plot_data$order, labels = plot_data$country) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Are you sure about your `aes` ? I think there is one parenthesis wrongly placed.

Comment: Yes there is something wrong because I get this error: "Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : argument "X" is missing, with no default"