# Reordering within groups not working using bar plot from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I originally asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495272/reordering-within-groups-not-working-on-ggplot-bar-plot) but it was marked as a duplicate and that I should follow this solution [How to order bars within all facets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710863/how-to-order-bars-within-all-facets).

Here is a dput of my top5_producers variable

```
structure(list(iso3_code = c("BGD", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "DEU", 
"EGY", "IDN", "IDN", "IND", "IND", "JPN", "KOR", "MEX", "MEX", 
"MMR", "NLD", "NLD", "PAK", "VNM", "VNM"), country = c("Bangladesh", 
"China", "China", "China", "Germany", "Egypt", "Indonesia", "Indonesia", 
"India", "India", "Japan", "South korea", "Mexico", "Mexico", 
"Myanmar", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Pakistan", "Viet Nam", 
"Viet Nam"), source_crop = c("Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", 
"Soybeans", "Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", "Maize", "Soybeans", 
"Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", "Sugar cane", "Maize", "Maize", 
"Maize", "Soybeans", "Sugar cane", "Oil palm fruit", "Soybeans", 
"Oil palm fruit", "Maize", "Soybeans"), FC_imports = c(1949020L, 
5457164L, 84505368L, 3062047L, 2201599L, 8652235L, 6311197L, 
4761885L, 8335597L, 2119435L, 15342352L, 9804926L, 14217581L, 
6540675L, 2205780L, 3867813L, 7534711L, 2817298L, 8228098L, 6273590L
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f953580b2e0>, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my code

```
scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
    reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
    ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
  }

reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

plot_data = top5_producers %>% 
  group_by(source_crop) %>% 
  arrange(source_crop, FC_imports) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number())

plot_data %>%  
  ggplot(aes(reorder_within(country, FC_imports, source_crop), FC_imports)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~source_crop, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=.5,colour='gray50'))
```

My output is

[image]

As you can see the values on the x-axis disappeared and there is text added to the y-values (compare to the image in the original question linked above). I honestly don't know what to make of this and would appreciate some help. I would like the bars in each facet to have different colours and that they should be ordered within each facet.

Session info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tmap_2.2            rnaturalearth_0.1.0 strucchange_1.5-2   sandwich_2.5-1      zoo_1.8-6          
 [6] WDI_2.6.0           ggpubr_0.2.3        magrittr_1.5        segmented_1.0-0     scales_1.0.0       
[11] spData_0.3.0        countrycode_1.1.0   janitor_1.2.0       data.table_1.12.2   forcats_0.4.0      
[16] stringr_1.4.0       dplyr_0.8.3         purrr_0.3.3         readr_1.3.1         tidyr_1.0.0        
[21] tibble_2.1.3        ggplot2_3.2.1       tidyverse_1.2.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-140       satellite_1.0.1    sf_0.7-4           lubridate_1.7.4    webshot_0.5.1     
 [6] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 httr_1.4.0         SnowballC_0.6.0    mapview_2.7.0      tools_3.6.1       
[11] backports_1.1.5    utf8_1.1.4         rgdal_1.4-3        R6_2.4.1           KernSmooth_2.23-15
[16] rgeos_0.4-3        DBI_1.0.0          lazyeval_0.2.2     colorspace_1.4-1   raster_2.8-19     
[21] withr_2.1.2        sp_1.3-1           tidyselect_0.2.5   leaflet_2.0.2      compiler_3.6.1    
[26] cli_1.1.0          rvest_0.3.3        xml2_1.2.0         labeling_0.3       classInt_0.3-3    
[31] digest_0.6.21      base64enc_0.1-3    dichromat_2.0-0    pkgconfig_2.0.3    htmltools_0.4.0   
[36] htmlwidgets_1.5.1  rlang_0.4.2        readxl_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.10    shiny_1.3.2       
[41] generics_0.0.2     jsonlite_1.6       crosstalk_1.0.0    tokenizers_0.2.1   Matrix_1.2-17     
[46] fansi_0.4.0        Rcpp_1.0.3         munsell_0.5.0      lifecycle_0.1.0    stringi_1.4.3     
[51] RJSONIO_1.3-1.1    tmaptools_2.0-1    grid_3.6.1         promises_1.0.1     crayon_1.3.4      
[56] lattice_0.20-38    haven_2.1.0        splines_3.6.1      hms_0.5.1          zeallot_0.1.0     
[61] pillar_1.4.2       ggsignif_0.6.0     stats4_3.6.1       codetools_0.2-16   XML_3.98-1.20     
[66] glue_1.3.1         tidytext_0.2.2     modelr_0.1.4       png_0.1-7          vctrs_0.2.0       
[71] httpuv_1.5.1       cellranger_1.1.0   gtable_0.3.0       assertthat_0.2.1   mime_0.6          
[76] lwgeom_0.1-7       xtable_1.8-4       broom_0.5.2        e1071_1.7-1        janeaustenr_0.1.5 
[81] later_0.8.0        class_7.3-15       viridisLite_0.3.0  units_0.6-3        ellipsis_0.3.0    
[86] spDataLarge_0.3.1
```

Comment: Can you please post your sessionInfo()? I have run this locally and appeared to get the results that you want, might have something to do with package versions, but I'm checking the rest

Comment: I have added session info, but the solution that Stefan posted below worked fine and it is much cleaner since it uses a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidytext::reorder_within` and `tidytext::scale_x_reordered` should do the trick:

```
plot_data %>%  
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(country = tidytext::reorder_within(
    country, FC_imports, source_crop)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = country, y = FC_imports, fill = source_crop)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~source_crop, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  tidytext::scale_x_reordered()
```

See the blog post by [Julia Silge](https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/).